# tf.exe get for different user

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

I use the following command to get the latest version of a branch for a specific user (not the one running the process):

```
tf get $/MyProject/Development /version:WmyPC;otherUser /login:otherUser,otherPassword
```

Bt I keep getting:

> The operation cannot be completed because the user (otherUser) does
>   not have one or more required permissions (Use) for workspace...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, when you create a workspace it is a 'Private Workspace' - this means that the person who created it is the only person who can "use" it (which is why you get that specific error message).

What you will want to do is change the workspace to a 'Public Workspace' - this updates the permissions and allows multiple people to use the same workspace, but using their own credentials.

For more information, see my blog post [TFS2010: Public Workspaces](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/granth/archive/2009/11/08/tfs2010-public-workspaces.aspx).

Comment: also for tfs 2008 you can specify -login:DOMAIN\user,password

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get the files on your local machine with the credentials of someone else. It is not executing the TF under other credentials.

In other words, you still use the workspace mapping of yourself.

You need to use the RUNAS command to fullfil your task: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/tfsversioncontrol/thread/20b6f678-4657-4b14-a114-5eeb232934e2/

Comment: I'm trying to run tf.exe with my credentials, but I want to get latest version of another (TFS) user

Comment: Why do you want to get the latest version of another user? Did the other user checkin his changes? Or do you want to port the local changes of the other user to your system? In the latter case, you can use shelvesets.